# I want to add a class attribute to row of table and remove this attribute from other sibling row by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a `class="selected"` attribute to a row click by user and remove this attribute from other siblings. Because I will get this row by its class attribute on a button click. I have tried so many j Queries but no j Query is working. Please give me a solution which can help me out.

This is my table on loading the page

```
<table id="saptable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>SAP Quantity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>121</td>
                <td>register121</td>
                <td>34344</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('tr').click(function() {
  $('tr').removeClass('selected'); //remove the class from all tr
  $(this).addClass('selected'); //add to clicked tr

})
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="saptable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Code</th>
      <th>SAP Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        121
      </td>
      <td>
        register121
      </td>
      <td>
        34344
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        121
      </td>
      <td>
        register121
      </td>
      <td>
        34344
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove class from all tr and then add to the current.

```
$('#saptable tbody tr').click(function(){
    $('#saptable tbody tr').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

You can keep the last selected row and remove the selected only from this row instead of removing from all rows. It will be more efficient solution.

```
$prevRow = null;
$('#saptable tbody tr').click(function(){
    if($prevRow != null)  
          $prevRow.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $prevRow = $(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery:

```
var lastSelected;

$("table tr").click(function() {
  $(lastSelected).removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  lastSelected = this;
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwaz1mxn/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#saptable tr").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="saptable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Code</th>
      <th>SAP Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        121
      </td>
      <td>
        register121
      </td>
      <td>
        34344
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        222
      </td>
      <td>
        register222
      </td>
      <td>
        78778
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `siblings()` method to search for siblings.

```
$("#saptable tbody > tr").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: it wont work if the tr is on thead and the click tr is in tbody

Comment: @anshulgupta set a breakpoint in browser developer console and see what happens...

Comment: i do this like... <script type="text/javascript">
        $("tr").live('click',function () {
            $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected')
        });          
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#addtobomid').on('click', function (e) {
            alert($("#saptable tr.selected td:first").html());
        });
    </script>